# Slick slider: Border+circuar radius option

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

When I try to apply 50% border-radius the slider items, they only look only more oval.
Setting border on item goofs up slider controls.
Fixed width/height is not very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

On applying 50% `Border-radius` the items look oval because on setting this value it results in excessively rounded corners . For  slightly rounded corners try the percentage value near about 10 % and apply this property to the container element. you can also set the `overflow` property to prevent images from exceeding the border.

Comment: sorry, i did not mention that i want to make them circular